# azure ad angular tutorial

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory

I'm currently following this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular#angular-interceptor), but I'm a little troubled, please help me.
Can someone tell me how to put these javascript code in the corresponding file.

First, include the Interceptor class as a provider to your application:

```typescript
    import { MsalInterceptor, MsalModule } from "@azure/msal-angular";
    import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
    
        @NgModule({
            // ...
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
                    useClass: MsalInterceptor,
                    multi: true
                }
            ]
        }
```

Next, provide a map of protected resources to `MsalModule.forRoot()` as `protectedResourceMap` and include those scopes in `consentScopes`. The URLs you provide in the `protectedResourceMap` collection are **case-sensitive**.

```js
    @NgModule({
      // ...
      imports: [
        // ...
        MsalModule.forRoot({
          auth: {
            clientId: 'Enter_the_Application_Id_here', // This is your client ID
            authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/Enter_the_Tenant_Info_Here', // This is your tenant info
            redirectUri: 'Enter_the_Redirect_Uri_Here' // This is your redirect URI
          },
          cache: {
            cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
            storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // Set to true for Internet Explorer 11
          },
        },
        {
          popUp: !isIE,
          consentScopes: [
            'user.read',
            'openid',
            'profile',
          ],
          unprotectedResources: [],
          protectedResourceMap: [
            ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']]
          ],
          extraQueryParameters: {}
        })
      ],
    });
```

Finally, retrieve a user's profile with an HTTP request:

```typescript
    const graphMeEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me";
    
    getProfile() {
      this.http.get(graphMeEndpoint).toPromise()
        .then(profile => {
          this.profile = profile;
        });
    }
```

Get a user token silently

```typescript
    const requestObj = {
        scopes: ["user.read"]
    };
    
    this.authService.acquireTokenSilent(requestObj).then(function (tokenResponse) {
        // Callback code here
        console.log(tokenResponse.accessToken);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Add the following code to log out a user:

```typescript
    logout() {
      this.authService.logout();
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the Interceptor class that automatically acquires tokens for outgoing requests that use the Angular http client in MSAL Angular you need to make the changes in the respective pages

**app.module.ts**

```
import { MsalInterceptor, MsalModule } from "@azure/msal-angular";
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

@NgModule({
    // ...
    providers: [
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: MsalInterceptor,
            multi: true
        }
    ]
}
```

With in the same file set **Msal.Module.forRoot** inside imports as below

```
@NgModule({
  // ...
  imports: [
    // ...
    MsalModule.forRoot({
      auth: {
        clientId: 'Enter_the_Application_Id_here', // This is your client ID
        authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/Enter_the_Tenant_Info_Here', // This is your tenant info
        redirectUri: 'Enter_the_Redirect_Uri_Here' // This is your redirect URI
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
        storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // Set to true for Internet Explorer 11
      },
    },
    {
      popUp: !isIE,
      consentScopes: [
        'user.read',
        'openid',
        'profile',
      ],
      unprotectedResources: [],
      protectedResourceMap: [
        ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']]
      ],
      extraQueryParameters: {}
    })
  ],
});
```

To retrieve a user's profile with an HTTP request you can use any component or with in a component like below.

```
 constructor(private authService: MsalService, private http: HttpClient) { }

  getProfile() {
    this.http.get(GRAPH_ENDPOINT)
      .toPromise().then(profile => {
        this.profile = profile;
      });
  }
```

To set the logout function in the `app.component.ts`

```
 logout() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }
```

Please refer this [document](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/99f1ffbc689d4beb3810b9ed9a0260f713f6c246/lib/msal-angular/docs/configuration.md#msalmoduleforroot) for more information and there is a [GitHub sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/ec094d89bd98fe9fd11b49d254bee3c6c7cdd105/samples/msal-angular-samples/angular6-sample-app) which can help you in implementation reference